# Start speech recognizer on Android using Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, speech-recognition

Currently I'm making a Phonegap application.
I want to combine augmented reality en speech input.
There is a plugin for Phonegap called SpeechRecognizer, But I can't get it to work.

My header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="SpeechRecognizer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function speechOk() {
            alert('speech works');
        }

        function speechFail() {
            alert("speech doesn't work");
        }

        function onDeviceReady() {
            window.plugins.speechrecognizer.init(speechOk, speechFail);
        }

        $("#micButton").bind("touchstart", function() {     
            var requestCode = 4815162342;
            var maxMatches = 1;
            var promptString = "What do you want?";
            window.plugins.speechrecognizer.startRecognize(speechOk, speechFail, requestCode, maxMatches, promptString);
        });
    </script>
```

A picture of the project (config.xml):
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I got it to work just fine by following the readme.md on the github repo. Are you sure everything is spelled correctly? Initially I was having trouble because I mistyped it as **speechRecgonizer**. Also...do you have a speech recognizer app on your device? It worked for me on a Nexus7 but on an older device without a speech recognizer app, it failed. What happens if you do ``console.log(window.plugins.speechrecognizer)`` in the ``onDeviceReady()``? Finally, what do your logs say?

Comment: That's strange. I can't get it to work. My console logs: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'speechrecognizer' of undefined"

What do you meen with: do you have a speech recognizer app on your device? I have a Sony Xperia Z (android 4.1.2) so that can't be the problem right?

Comment: I've changed the min sdk version to 15 in the android manifest, now I don't get any console errors anymore, but now it doesn't log anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few problems.
First of all, the SDK version wasn't right. If you use the new cordova you also have to use the newest version of the plugin. This version requires SDK 15 or higher. (android manifest -> `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />`).
After that, for some reason the plugin init does not return anything.
I just triggerd the: window.plugins.speechrecognizer.startRecognize(); function on a button click, and it executes.

The javascript (you need jQuery for this code):

```
    $("#micButton").bind("touchstart", function() {        
        var requestCode = 4815162342;
        var maxMatches = 1;
        var promptString = "What do you want?";
        window.plugins.speechrecognizer.startRecognize(speechOk, speechFail, requestCode, maxMatches, promptString);
    });

    function speechOk(result) {
        var match, respObj;
        if (result) {
            respObj = JSON.parse(result);
            if (respObj) {
                var response = respObj.speechMatches.speechMatch[0];
                $("#searchField").val(response);
                $("#searchButton").trigger("touchstart");
            } 
        }
    }

    function speechFail(m) {
        navigator.notification.alert("Sorry, I couldn't recognize you.", function() {}, "Speech Fail");
    }
```

'#micButton' is the button you have to press to start the android voice recognition

'#searchField' is a input field wich gets the result from the voice recognition

Thanks to MrBillau for the good advice.

Comment: I have updated the plugin to remove the useless init method. The plugin is available there: https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer/ . Please create issues tickets if you encounter any bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Is not your fault, the `SpeechRecognizer.java` has a bug inside.

I had the same problem and I solved it with just replacing the `Speech Recognizer` plugin with and older version (like `2.0.0`), you can download it from [github](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SpeechRecognizer/v2.0.0).

It worked for me with `Phonegap 2.5.0`, guess it works in `2.6.0`.