# PhoneGap Android Speech Recognition

Tags: android, cordova, speech-recognition

I'm trying to translate this script https://github.com/GoogleChrome/webplatform-samples/tree/master/webspeechdemo into a android app based on Apache Cordova.

The problem is the script works only on Google Chrome browser and when I test it on my Android Phone it doesnt do much. Is there a way to emulate Google Chrome when my app starts ?

Thanks

Comment: This may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035194/start-speech-recognizer-on-android-using-phonegap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a speech recognition plugin for cordova: http://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin

And here is the talk the author gave at Phonegap Day US: 
http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.it/2013/10/my-phonegap-day-us-talk-on-speech.html

I haven't actually tried this plugin but looking at the video it seems good.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Another quick & easy alternative to add Speech Recognition into your Cordova app, is to use ng-speech-recognition directive:

[ng-speech-directive for AngularJS compatible Cordova](https://github.com/Devniz/ng-speech-recognition)